# Can a higher edition S60 Platform SDK build for lower?

Tags: ide, nokia, s60

After installing the [S60 3rd Edition FP1](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/4a7149a5-95a5-4726-913a-3c6f21eb65a5/S60-SDK-0616-3.0-mr.html) Platform **SDK**, with the [Carbide C++](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Resources_and_Information/Tools/IDEs/Carbide.c++/) **IDE**,

you **can** build programs for phones that support:

- 3rdE-FP1

but **can you also** target phones that support the following?

- 3rdE
- 2ndE-FP3
- 2ndE-FP2
- 2ndE-FP1
- 2ndE
- 1stE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build 3rdE but for older phones you must install SDKs for 1st and 2nd.
If your applications are not using any fancy FP3 settings then having one 2nd SDK is enough.

Answer (score -1):

I would have thought that so long as you only use APIs that are available in the oldest version then due to Symbian's binary compatibility any newer SDK should be able to build for an older release.

Comment: 3rd edition programs don't run on 1st and 2nd edition phones and opposite